# is it possible to add the .live() function to a getJson call?

Tags: jquery, live, getjson

I have this code:

The problem is, i cant add the 'active' class to the getJson's images inside the mac div. Would integrating a live function here help at all?

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=59597329@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img src='" + item.media.m + "'></img>").appendTo("#mac");
    });
});

$("#mac img:first").addClass('active');

function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#mac img.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#mac img:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#mac img.active');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );
});
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you want. Why can't you add the class inside the callback? `live` is only for event handling. Also your setup seems to be prone to errors. E.g. you cannot know that the DOM is ready when the callback is called. `$("#mac img:first").addClass('active');` won't work either.

Comment: this is all in a document.ready function

Comment: So you say all the code posted above is in `document.ready`? Why do you have another one (`$(function() {setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );});`) then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what you actually want to do. One solution would be to put all code that has to work on DOM inside the `ready` handler and fire the interval once the data is loaded:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#mac img.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#mac img:last');
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#mac img.active');
    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=59597329@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img src='" + item.media.m + "'></img>").appendTo("#mac");
        });
        $("#mac img:first").addClass('active');
        setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @Felix, thanks again for this, any ideas why the slideSwitch wouldnt work in IE? Works great in Firefox...

Comment: images load in fine, but the slideSwitch never initialises and therefore doesnt cycle through the images..

Comment: @benhowdle89: I don't, I have no IE to test the code. As you are actually only using jQuery, there should be no problem.

Comment: Hmm, not that i really mind that IE users miss out but just curious